# Query 2 keys from Python dict

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, aws-lambda

I have a piece of code to get value of a defined key in a dict. It works great and return a list, but now I want to get 1 more key and probably save it into a dict

```
def find(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result
```

I don't know much about Python, I could run this function twice to achieve my goal but would like to know how can it be modified so I only run once.

EDIT: my goal is to get the values of `SnapshotId` and `StartTime` from the following dictionary, there will be several `Snapshots` list being returned

```
{
    'Snapshots': [
        {
            'SnapshotId': 'string',
            'VolumeId': 'string',
            'State': 'pending'|'completed'|'error',
            'StateMessage': 'string',
            'StartTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'Progress': 'string',
            'OwnerId': 'string',
            'Description': 'string',
            'VolumeSize': 123,
            'OwnerAlias': 'string',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Encrypted': True|False,
            'KmsKeyId': 'string',
            'DataEncryptionKeyId': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

This is my current code:

```
def find(keys, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k in keys:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result

def findDate(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')   

    response = ec2.describe_snapshots(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'volume-id',
                'Values': [
                    VOLUMEID,
                ]
            },
        ]
    )

    recentSnapshots_id = list(find('SnapshotId', response))

    recentSnapshots_date = list(findDate('StartTime', response))

    print (dict(zip(recentSnapshots_id, recentSnapshots_date)))
```

Comment: Just pass a list instead of a key, call it keys, then check `if k in keys`

Comment: or, to have a nicer interface: `def find(dictionary, *keys)`

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, do i only need to pass in a list with the same function or I need to add more code in the function?

Comment: Because it's a `<genexp>`, you could probably just loop through it twice to get two values... I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have strict structure, don't iterate over all the values. Instead:

```
[{'SnapshotId': s['SnapshotId'], 'StartTime':s['StartTime']}  for s in data['Snapshots']]
```

or

```
{ s['SnapshotId']:s['StartTime'] for s in data['Snapshots'] }
```

for an id->time dictionary.

Comment: I don't know Python, how would I use this? is it an function?